# Amazon Api Gateway file upload with special character filename

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I m trying to file upload with special character in key field( + character), it is getting an error like below. I m using amazon s3 java sdk.

--> keyname = **debug22019 -+(.txt** is not working.

--> keyname = **debug22019 -(.txt** is working.

> 2019-02-01 13:27:21 - Executing request PUT /dev/bucket/530/debug22019%20-%2B%28.txt HTTP/1.1
>
> 2019-02-01 13:27:21 - http-outgoing-0 >> PUT /dev/bucket/530/debug22019%20-%2B%28.txt HTTP/1.1
>
> 2019-02-01 13:27:21 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: ********.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com

Error is:

> `SignatureDoesNotMatch`The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.********AWS4-HMAC-SHA256

Comment: This sounds like it might be related to a long-standing quirk in the way S3 handles the `+` character in the path.  Specifically, S3 considers `+` in the request as equivalent to `%20` and not `%2B` to be a different character.  It looks like API Gateway or another component (is there a Lambda function involved?) may be doing this "right" way -- which is considered wrong by S3.